# Difference between 2 records timestamp sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE result (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tag int(11) NOT NULL,
  timestamp timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  value double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY nasudnBBEby333412dsa (timestamp, tag)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=115 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I would like to calculate the difference between two consecutive days that have the same column tag. For example, in timestamp:

```
|   1 |   1 | 2017-06-18 00:00:00 |    7.3 |
|   2 |   1 | 2017-06-17 00:00:00 |    7.4 |
```

I want to result: -0.1

Which query should i write?

Comment: Explain detail what you expect? how do you get 0.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

1) Use join to select value of next consecutive day.

2) then calculate difference

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.tag, r1.value AS CURRENT_VALUE, r2.value AS NEXT_VALUE, (
r1.value - r2.value
) AS DIFF, r1.timestamp
FROM  `result` r1
LEFT JOIN result r2 ON r2.tag=r1.tag AND r2.`timestamp` = r1.`timestamp` + INTERVAL 1 
DAY WHERE r2.value IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY r1.timestamp
```

Output

[image]

Comment: then select only diff in selection

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: try this    SELECT (
r1.value - r2.value
) AS DIFF
FROM  result r1
LEFT JOIN result r2 ON r2.tag=r1.tag AND r2.timestamp = r1.timestamp + INTERVAL 1 
DAY WHERE r2.value IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY r1.timestamp

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to store date values, you can use `date`, so there is no time component.

Second, you can do this with `join`:

```
select r.*, (r.value - rprev.value) as diff
from results r left join
     results rprev
     on r.tag = rprev.tag and
        r.timestamp = rprev.timestamp + interval 1 day;
```

Comment: @peppe71-19 . . . Then `select` only that expression.